# How to correctly determine the type of variable google.protobuf.Any?

Tags: go, protobuf-go

Please tell me what is wrong in this code, why the type is not determined for the variable, for the transmitted url type google.protobuf.Any?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry"
)

func main() {
    var res protoregistry.MessageTypeResolver = protoregistry.GlobalTypes
    typeUrl := "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue"
    fmt.Println(protoreflect.FullName(typeUrl))
    msgType, err := protoregistry.GlobalTypes.FindMessageByName(protoreflect.FullName("google.protobuf.StringValue"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(msgType)

    msgType, err = res.FindMessageByURL(typeUrl)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(msgType)
}
```

proto: not found

proto: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `protoregistry.NotFound` because there are not message types got registered in `protoregistry.GlobalTypes`.

To register `google.protobuf.Any`, you should import the package `google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb`. And `google.protobuf.Any` is registered by the `init` function of that package (see the [source code](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/808c66411fe76c839a68168654228446fbdc1ecf/types/known/anypb/any.pb.go#L458-L495)).

To register `google.protobuf.StringValue`, you should import the package `google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/wrapperspb`.

Here is the updated demo that finds the message byte of `google.protobuf.StringValue`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry"
    // importing the package solely for its side-effects (initialization).
    // See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Import_declarations.
    _ "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb"
    _ "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/wrapperspb"
)

func main() {
    res := protoregistry.GlobalTypes
    fmt.Println("NumMessages:", res.NumMessages())

    msgType, err := protoregistry.GlobalTypes.FindMessageByName("google.protobuf.StringValue")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(msgType)

    msgType, err = res.FindMessageByURL("type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(msgType)
}
```